# Implementar la sobrecarga de los operadores << y >> fuera de la clase con plantillas

Tags: c++, template

Estaba intentado recordar lo poco que sé de C++, y estaba recreando la típica clase del Punto2D. Cuando he querido sacar la implementación de los operadores `<<` y `>>` fuera de la clase, me da errores.

Esta sería la clase:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Punto2D
{
public:
    Punto2D();
    Punto2D(T x, T y);
    Punto2D (const Punto2D& P);
    T CoordX();
    T CoordY();
    void SetCoordX (T x);
    void SetCoordY (T y);
    void SetCoords (T x, T y);
    Punto2D operator + (const Punto2D<T>& P);
    Punto2D operator = (const Punto2D<T>& P);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Punto2D<T>& P);   
    friend istream& operator>>(istream &is, Punto2D<T>& P);
    
private:
        T m_x,m_y;
};

int main()
{
    Punto2D<float> P1;
    cout<<"P1: "<<P1<<endl;        
    return 0;
}

template <typename T>
Punto2D<T>::Punto2D()
{
    m_x=0;
    m_y=0;
};
template <typename T>
Punto2D<T>::Punto2D(T x, T y)
{
    m_x=x;
    m_y=y;
};
template <typename T>
Punto2D<T>::Punto2D (const Punto2D& P)
{
    m_x = P.m_x;
    m_y = P.m_y;
}
template <typename T>
T Punto2D<T>::CoordX()
{
    return m_x;
}
template <typename T>
T Punto2D<T>::CoordY()
{
    return m_y;
}
template <typename T>
void Punto2D<T>::SetCoordX (T x)
{
    m_x=x;
}
template <typename T>
void Punto2D<T>::SetCoordY (T y)
{
    m_y=y;
}
template <typename T>
void Punto2D<T>::SetCoords (T x, T y)
{
    m_x=x;
    m_y=y;
}
template <typename T>
Punto2D<T> Punto2D<T>::operator + (const Punto2D<T>& P)
{
    Punto2D  temp;
    temp.m_x = m_x + P.m_x;
    temp.m_y = m_y + P.m_y;
    return temp;
}
template <typename T>
Punto2D<T> Punto2D<T>::operator = (const Punto2D<T>& P)
{
    if (this != &P )
    {
        m_x = P.m_x;
        m_y = P.m_y;
    }
}
template <typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Punto2D<T>& P)
{
    os << P.m_x << ',' << P.m_y;
    return os;
}
template <typename T>
istream& operator>>(istream &is, Punto2D<T>& P)
{
    is >> P.m_x >> P.m_y;
    is.ignore();
    return is;
}
```

Estos son los errores que da (se repite varias veces):

> friend declaration ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const
> Punto2D&)’ declares a non-template function
> [-Wnon-template-friend]|
>
> referencia a `operator>>(std::istream&, Punto2D&)' sin definir|

Y la verdad es que no sé resolver este tema. La implementación dentro de la clase sí funciona.

Comment: qué errores te da?

Comment: Y dónde has implementado exactamente esos operadores?

Comment: He editado la pregunta ponniendo toda la clase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error ocurre porque las implementaciones de los operadores son plantillas. Entonces cuando declaras la función `friend` debes indicar la plantilla también:

```
template <typename T>
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Punto2D<T>& P);

template <typename T>
friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Punto2D<T>& P);
```

En una clase normal, el código funcionaría. Pero en esta aparece otro error:

```
error: declaration of template parameter ‘T’ shadows template parameter
      template <typename T>
                ^~~~~~~~
```

Este sucede porque son dos plantillas diferentes y su parámetro tiene el mismo nombre que el de la plantilla de la clase. Es como si tuvieras dos variables con el mismo nombre, una local y una global. Una oculta a la otra.

Simplemente tienes que darle otro nombre. Por ejemplo:

```
template <typename U>
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Punto2D<U>& P);

template <typename U>
friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Punto2D<U>& P);
```

---

Por consistencia también deberías cambiar el nombre de los parámetros en las implementaciones, así:

```
template <typename U>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Punto2D<U>& P)
{
    ...
}
template <typename U>
istream& operator>>(istream &is, Punto2D<U>& P)
{
    ...
}
```

Pero el compilador no se queja si no lo haces así que queda a tu criterio.

**Puedes ver y probar el código final [aquí](https://tio.run/##nZXNbqMwEMfvPMW0K6VETaNmj8HxpX0ApKVSc6pY42QtgY1sUwVVffbUgPkKkC7NobFnpr/5az4ckqYPR0LO51@MkziLKCAmlJY0TLDT2lRtyhTjR@BhQlUaEgpKR57jaJqkcahNoM5TWnghwA6JQ6XAz7gWv5@dDyfN/saMbB0wH2t1l17vGsBpBQHkfTO4RHCl6@sCfOsP4EkIGb26/fu@vr8LFsEfqqsoKPBjnn3hycc8CqYkiZTKUAsJ9xfqUIBbgYPo3VR0GT5Sxxdceg6SUR6Bbc2iASLktja1gj78ZRacXcIxdhsbM/BLbPG/TirZu6FWba2akLydVslb7jmfJjXjGpKQcXdpRqBTE3SIRagx@JsKRESmEbr1N1u4RcjfIGQ0xV5NLWMk1Znk8GjIU0PX1nW7bYbMZja6do@ePebF0Qj8f0wzCR3cqcXl83AjQ91yzZz4a/Pd0K2hyDGRIoBuknovLNIWriTOAOyHgCsKys3pMi42r1@22RS7pQ2lqvhcSnejp/v4bRt77O/egv7gV5voNTu5rvpd/L3vdt368tKXW1/uddtRgX6qdndVLTuAq/8xBTc7WPiwLI0fzZYPhnQwqIXhc1yceXd@9JJZaUIBQlXu4nC3uqvv/fII5U3mv/LYwWL42NVFUYCxzWwPNiVTa3bkQtL6t8dqYKWG8/kL).**

Comment: Mateo, de esta forma me da el error `'friend' used outside of class`

Comment: @user agregué un link para que puedas ver el código y probarlo.

Comment: Ahora sí. Me faltaba indicar dentro de la clase que los operadores sobrecargados eran una plantilla con otro parámetro. Vamos, que me faltaba poner `template <typename U>` dentro de la clase y antes de cada definición de cada sobrecarga. De hecho no había leído bien tu respuesta y ahora entiendo bien a qué te referías con el hecho de tener que definir otro parámetro en la plantilla para no solapar el de la clase. Gracias!